# Plot CSV data as a graph

Tags: c, linux, graphics, csv

What would be the best approach to plot a chart, using C (on Linux), based on data input from a CSV file?

Thank you!

Comment: What sort of graph do you want to draw from the data?

Comment: sir just simple graph i will define interval. for example i have row having data 23 45 67 546.......... i will draw at time 1 val is 23 , 2 val 45 so on thanks

Comment: sir just points which i will join by line

Comment: yes dave sir i have to use c programming

Comment: sir i have retrieve value from file in the array. but dnt know how to plot them does c supports any graphs.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the mighty `gnuplot` it seems to have a [C API](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/)

And examples: http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/gnuplot_i/index.html

Answer (score 0):

To make a graph in C you'll have to use a graphics library (unless you mean an ascii-art graph).

Two such libraries are:

- The excellent *Allegro* gaming library (see examples [here](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Allegro_examples))
- The [SDL library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer)